# Upgrade SQL server without disturbing Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a very basic question for which i am not able to find the answer.
I have a dev box with Sharepoint 2013 foundation  and SQL server 2008 R2 installed on it. I need to use SSRS web parts on the sharepoint. As per this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492257.aspx) they are not compatible. So i need to upgrade the SQL server to 2014 version. I do not want the existing sharepoint to be affected.

Please suggest how can i achieve this. Any tutorial or guidance will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure that you have May 2014 Cumulative Update on SharePoint farm.
  Where

> SQL Server 2014 requires the May 2014 Cumulative Update to be installed.

- ake a full farm backup and database backup to allow rollback.
- An in-place upgrade and side by side upgrade provide this. in place is much faster. ( My recommendation would be to install SQL Server 2014 instance and then backup and migrate the database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014)
- You need to make sure you first upgrade SQl Server 2008 R2 to SP2/Sp3.

For more details check [this](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2014/migrating-sql-server-2014) or this [vedio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfGp-65Cr4k)

If your aim only to host SSRS try to use native mode rather than integrated mode and hold it inside performance point web part as mentioned [here](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/08/29/view-ssrs-report-using-performancepoint-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you can do it without disturbing the SharePoint. It is recommended that when you upgrade your SQL server either In-Place of move to new server then Shut Down the SharePoint Servers or At min Shut down all SharePoint services.

Also you have to meet the minimum requirement for the SQL 2014 support to SharePoint 2013.